# Binary classification always outputs 1

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm making my first steps on `keras` and I'm trying to do binary classification on the cancer dataset available in `scikit-learn`

```
# load dataset
from sklearn import datasets
cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
cancer.data

# dataset into pd.dataframe
import pandas as pd
donnee = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data = cancer.data, columns = cancer.feature_names), 
                   pd.DataFrame(data = cancer.target, columns = ["target"])
                      ], axis = 1)

# train/test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(donnee.loc[:, donnee.columns != "target"], donnee.target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 1)
```

I'm trying to follow keras' tutorial here : https://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras

The thing is, I always get the same loss value (`6.1316862406430541`), and the same accuracy (`0.61538461830232527`), because the predictions are always 1.

I'm not sure if it's because of a code error :

- I don't know, maybe the shape of `X_train` is wrong ?
- Or maybe I'm doing something wrong with `epochs` and/or `batch_size`.

Or if it's because of the network itself :

- if I'm not mistaken, all 1 predictions is possible if there's no biases to the layers, and I don't know yet how they're initialized
- But maybe it's something else, maybe 1 layer only is too few ? (if so, I wonder why keras' tutorial is 1 layer only...)

Here is my code, if you have any idea :

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

from keras.layers import Dense

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=30))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer = 'rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy']
              )

model.fit(X_train.as_matrix(), y_train.as_matrix().reshape(426, -1), epochs=5, batch_size=32)

loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(X_test.as_matrix(), y_test.as_matrix(), batch_size=128)
loss_and_metrics

classes = model.predict(X_test.as_matrix(), batch_size=128)
classes
```

Comment: can you add a small data sample, a few of you x_train columns and your y train column?

Comment: You can get the data by running the code on top of the question. The full dataset is 569 rows x 31 columns, it's not gonna melt your computer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very usual case. If you check the histogram of your data you will see that there are data points in your dataset which coordinates spans from `0` to `100`. When you feed such data to neural network input to `sigmoid` might be so big that it will suffer from underflow. In order to scale data, you could use either [`MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) or [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) thanks to what you'll make your data to have a span suitable for neural network computations.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I understood the problem thanks to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319602/4348534. The problem can also be fixed by not chaining relu before a sigmoid, but multiple sigmoid for instance.

Comment: Actually - this might cause similar problems in a first `sigmoid` layer. This arises due to `sigmoid` saturation.